# text not wrapping around some floated images, wraps in IE & FF but not chrome, safari

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

I have a hand-coded site @ hartbro.com Part of the site is a blog, in which I include pictures. Here's the HTML code around one of the images that's causing trouble.

```
<a href="blogcontent/090811.jpg" class="img">
<img src="blogcontent/090811.jpg" alt="Downed trees" width="25%" class="floatright" /></a>
The storm left as quickly as it came. The sky cleared up and we were glad that the oppressive heat had let up.
```

What I've noticed is that, on some of the blog entries that include more than one image, the 2nd image isn't really floating like its supposed to be, with the text wrapping around it. I figure its got to be some sort of conflict with some CSS that I have that's causing the problem but I just can't figure out what it is.

I don't understand how it works in FF & IE but not Chrome or Safari??

Here's all of the relevant CSS, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.

```
img{
    margin:10px;
}

img.floatleft{
    float:left;
}
img.floatright{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: aside from your horrible class naming, why do you have `width: fixed`? i'm pretty sure your problem is there...

Comment: Looks fine (the same) to me in both Chrome and FF... but the mascot image is running out of the block (appearing over the red horizontal line) you can prevent this by setting `clear:both` on the line to make sure all content, including floated content, above it is complete before it appears.

Comment: The page in question has some AJAX elements and when I use those to "refresh" the content (not refreshing the entire page), the float and wrapping seems to work fine. Also, when I reload the page, occasionally everything lines up. Could it be something to do with how the images are loading??

Comment: sorry, the width:fixed thing was just one of many solution I was trying to play around with, it wans't in my original code when I noticed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width for both img.floatleft and img.floatright and adjust. You may get it sure

Comment: the thing is, the images that I use are generally different sizes, so I wouldn't want to set the width to a fixed, absolute size. Are you saying that's what I should do though?

That's why I was trying to play around with the "width:fixed;" in my CSS. I usually set the width as a percentage in the img tag.